# Requirement for multiple GeoTIFF layers in a store

Tags: geotiff-tiff, geoserver-rest-api

I have a folder to which GeoTIFF files would be incoming from a source.
So now I have to basically, as and when the file arrives, send the file into a store in GeoServer and publish the layer.

I was working with coverage stores for testing but understood that coverage stores can only take one image per store.

So I'm looking for options, wherein i can publish multiple GeoTIFF images from the same store using REST API. What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: You want an image mosaic store

Comment: But once a image mosaic store is created, can I then add another geotiff file in the folder and then update the layer in the store or would i have to create a new store altogether?

Comment: You can add more images and recreate the index via the rest API